# Localization of javascripts and jquery alerts

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to localize the javascript and jquery in asp.net (.net 4)?

Is there any proper examples with c#?

Comment: http://madskristensen.net/post/Localize-text-in-JavaScript-files-in-ASPNET.aspx probably?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx

This site provides a demo application of globalization of jquery in .net

Answer (score 1):

I usually create one localization script per language for a plugin. The script contains variables with all strings that the plugin use. Other scripts let you define all text strings in the plugin options.

I then use ASP.NET to define which language (since the user might not want the language reported by the browser).

In your master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.yourplugin.resources.<%= userLanguage %>.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.yourplugin.js"></script>
```